# Efficient collision detection in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-physics, collision

I have a problem with a game that I'm doing. I basically have objects that are in a map and I have to check for each of them if they collide with the walls (and then do something). Since was working with AS2, I thought about doing the same way: I drew a picture with only the walls, so with only rectangles and everything else in between is transparent (does not exist, then the floor for example). In AS2 I put the image to the screen, let's call it wall, and then I did a hitTest to wall with every object. That is for instance, the object was actually on the image, since that the transparent parts were part of it, but the function was testing only on the visible parts, and so with the walls. So it worked.

Now in AS3 there is no `HitTest` but `hitTestObject`, which I used, and I do for example `wall.hitTestObject(object)`. The problem is that this function is as if it doens't see the transparencies, and the objects while not touching the walls collide with them!

I found the `PixelPerfectCollisionDetection` that actually solves the problem but it is huge and heavy so in my case, with so many objects to be tested (at least 60) at each frame, the game slows down a lot!

What I need is a function like `hitTestObject` (i don't need a lot of accuracy!) that take care of the transparent parts of an image.

How can I do?

Comment: In AS3 there are high performance physics libraries that you can use like Box2D.

Comment: you could try optimising your collision detection - eg: check that 2 objects are within suitable distance of each other before using (the slow) hitTestObject.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, physics/game libraries will have this code built-in for you and should work out of the box.

But if you want to build it yourself, or even introduce your own optimizations, the first step (which is very inexpensive) is checking for bounds collision using entirely built-in functionality of `DisplayObject.getBounds` and `Rectangle.intersects` (though you must do so in a consistent coordinate space, i.e. the stage):

```
if (obj1.getBounds(stage).intersects(obj2.getBounds(stage)) {
  // Cheap bounds intersection is true, now do pixel-perfect detection...
}
```

Then if the bounds check is true, perform the pixel-perfect collision detection.

It seems that [BitmapData.hitTest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29) is your best bet - see a [blog post by Mike Chambers](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/).

Prior to this method, if you're interested in neat techniques, there was a method outlined by Grant Skinner in [his blog](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2005/08/flash_8_shape_b.html).  It's quite a clever algorithm using built-in bitmap routines (aka, fairly fast), creating a BitmapData only as large as the overlapping region (or even scaling that down), and drawing the two objects into specific channels of the bitmapdata, then using `BitmapData.getColorBoundsRect()` to determine if there are any pixels touch.  I'm guessing BitmapData.hitTest is faster, but it'd be fun to compare.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and to be honest i found the easy way to get rid of that is just generating a "mask" layer for the collisions. You can always place this under your background so it doesn't show, or change the transparencies and whatsoever. Do this in Flash, and after "covering" with rectangles (or whatever) the collisions, just select them all and make that a movie clip.

I'm guessing since you made the symbol in Flash, it obviously knows that even if the symbol consists of several individual drawings or whatever, it's not just an image.

For me this worked fine .