# as3 hitTestPoint detecting alpha

Tags: actionscript-3, alpha, hittest

I am trying to make maze where the user draws with mouse and if they hit the wall it erases the line they just drew. I have a png file with alpha that creates the walls of the maze.

**I need the user to draw on the alpha but when they hit a non alpha it will trigger an action and erase the line.**

Here is the line I am having issues with:

```
if (myshape.hitTestPoint(theBall.x,theBall.y, true))
```

Here is the full code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.JointStyle;
    import flash.display.LineScaleMode;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;



    public class MazeClass extends Sprite
    {
        //Are we drawing or not?
        private var drawing:Boolean;
        public var myshape:Shape;
        public var alreadyDrawn:Shape;
        public var theBall:Ball = new Ball();
        //alreadyDrawn = new Shape();


        public function MazeClass()
        {

            if (stage)
            {

                myshape = new Shape();
                myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12,0x000000);
                addChild(myshape);
                drawing = false;//to start with
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, draw);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
                //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkIt);

                addChild(theBall);
            }
        }


        public function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            myshape.graphics.moveTo( mouseX, mouseY);
            drawing = true;
        }


        public function draw(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            if (drawing)
            {
                //checkIt();
                myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);

                if (myshape.hitTestPoint(theBall.x,theBall.y, true))
                {
                    trace("Hit A WALL!");
                    myshape.graphics.clear();
                    myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0xFFFFFF);
                    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
                }
            }
        }


        public function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            drawing = false;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, you need some kind of pixel perfect collision detection in here. Chech SO for similar questions, I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846470/efficient-collision-detection-in-as3 though it might not be exactly your case. There are more obviously. And check the PPCD library.

Comment: This article of Mike Chambers can helps as well: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to test the colour of the map bitmapdata pixel that corresponds to the "player's position" (the end of the drawn line, in this case):

```
var testPixel:uint = _myBitmapData.getPixel(xPosition, yPosition);
```

Or you can use .getPixel32 which includes alpha in the returned uint.

Comment: Interesting. What would that look like in my code and where would I put it? On the Enter Frame?

Comment: If your maze is 'created' on stage at the same scale as your bitmap you could replace your hitTest code (in 'draw') with the code I've provided above, where _myBitmapData is the BitmapData object of your map Bitmap and xPosition/yPosition are mouseX/mouseY. If the stage map is scaled relative to the map bitmap, you can scale xPosition and yPosition by that proportion (ie; If the map is drawn 2x larger than the Bitmap, divide your mouse cords by 2 to check the corresponding pixel). Once you have the pixel colour, check if it is the colour of a wall.

Comment: Note that, if you DO have to divide your mouse position values, you should use Math.floor(mouseX / stageMapScale) to disregard any fractional values (.getPixel needs int values for its pixel check). One other thought: If your stage map is not positioned at 0, 0 on stage, you will have to subtract out those coordinates (so that when the mouse is at the top left corner of the stage map you are checking pixel 0, 0 of the BitmapData). I hope that's all clear!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was more thinking, like what part do I add my code in. For example, do I add it where I declare values or do I put it in a function and its called several times or an enter frame many times per second or an if statement like... if (drawing). I did get it to work. I am going to post my working code. I had to add a movie clip that I drag rather than the mouse itself and the line I am drawing. It would be nice to know how to do the mouse as well.

Answer (score 0):

**I FOUND A WORKING SOLUTION:**

I found a working solution thanks to [fsbmain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677424/fsbmain). Thank you. I am posting my full code in hopes that this can help someone else.

In the end I had to use another movieClip rather than the mouse, but this worked for me. Now instead of drawing anywhere in the maze they have to drag a little character named Beau thru the maze. This works better for me.

**It would be nice to know how to also detect if the mouse or the actual line I am drawing hit the wall as well. Maybe someone can make a suggestion. Nevertheless, thanks for helping me get this far.**

The short and essential code to make my movieClip detect the alpha can be found here. It really is very short compared to other complicated options I found. Here is the link: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.JointStyle;
    import flash.display.LineScaleMode;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.system.Capabilities;

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.*;

    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    import flash.display.Bitmap;

    import flash.geom.Matrix;

    public class MazeClass extends Sprite
    {
        //Are we drawing or not?
        private var drawing:Boolean;
        public var myshape:Shape;
        public var alreadyDrawn:Shape;
        public var theMap:*;

        public var swiper:Swiper = new Swiper();

        public var Beau:littleBeau = new littleBeau();

        //alreadyDrawn = new Shape();


        public var currentGalleryItem:Number = 1;
        public var totalGalleryItems:Number = 4;

        public var redClipBmpData:BitmapData;
        public var blueClipBmpData:BitmapData;
        public var  redRect:Rectangle;
        public var blueRect:Rectangle;

        public function MazeClass()
        {

            if (stage)
            {
                theMap = new MapOne();

                myshape = new Shape();
                myshape.graphics.lineStyle(33,0x0aa6df);
                addChild(myshape);
                drawing = false;//to start with
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, draw);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
                //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkIt);


                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_OptionsMenuHandler);

                Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;




                addChild(theMap);
                //theMap.height = stage.stageHeight - 200;
                theMap.theStart.alpha = 0;
                theMap.theFinish.alpha = 0;


                addChild(swiper);
                swiper.y = stage.stageHeight - swiper.height;
                swiper.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeToGoToNextPreviousFrame);

                addChild(Beau);
                Beau.x = theMap.theStart.x;
                Beau.y = theMap.theStart.y - swiper.height;

                Beau.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, BeauStartDrag);
                Beau.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, BeauStopDrag);



                redRect = theMap.getBounds(this);
                redClipBmpData = new BitmapData(redRect.width,redRect.height,true,0);
                redClipBmpData.draw(theMap);

                blueRect = Beau.getBounds(this);
                blueClipBmpData = new BitmapData(blueRect.width,blueRect.height,true,0);
                blueClipBmpData.draw(Beau);

                //blueClipBmpData.x = theMap.theStart.x;
                //blueClipBmpData.y = theMap.theStart.y - swiper.height;

                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

            }
        }




        public function enterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            //Beau.x = mouseX;
            //Beau.y = mouseY;

            if (redClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(theMap.x, theMap.y),
                                            255,
                                            blueClipBmpData,
                                            new Point(Beau.x, Beau.y),
                                            255

                                      ))
            {
                trace("hit");
                clearAll();
                //redClip.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
            }
            else
            {
                trace("No Hit");
            }
        }





        public function BeauStartDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            Beau.startDrag();
            drawing = true;
        }
        public function BeauStopDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            drawing = false;
            Beau.stopDrag();
        }

        public function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            myshape.graphics.moveTo( mouseX, mouseY);
        }
        //drawing = true;


        public function draw(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            if (drawing)
            {
                //checkIt();
                myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);


            }
        }


        public function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            //drawing = false;
        }


        public function fl_OptionsMenuHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if ((event.keyCode == 95) || (event.keyCode == Keyboard.MENU))
            {
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(0);
            }
        }

        public function clearAll()
        {
            myshape.graphics.clear();
            myshape.graphics.lineStyle(12, 0x0aa6df);
            myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY);
            Beau.x = theMap.theStart.x;
                    Beau.y = theMap.theStart.y - swiper.height;
                    drawing = false;
            Beau.stopDrag();
        }





        public function fl_SwipeToGoToNextPreviousFrame(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
        {
            if (event.offsetX == 1)
            {
                if (currentGalleryItem > 1)
                {
                    currentGalleryItem--;
                    trace("swipe Right");
                    clearAll();
                    removeChild(theMap);
                    theMap = new MapOne();
                    addChild(theMap);
                    theMap.height = stage.stageHeight - 200;

                    theMap.theStart.alpha = 0;
                    theMap.theFinish.alpha = 0;
                    addChild(Beau);
                    Beau.x = theMap.theStart.x;
                    Beau.y = theMap.theStart.y - swiper.height;
                }
            }
            else if (event.offsetX == -1)
            {
                if (currentGalleryItem < totalGalleryItems)
                {
                    currentGalleryItem++;
                    trace("swipe Left");
                    clearAll();
                    removeChild(theMap);
                    theMap = new MapTwo();
                    addChild(theMap);
                    theMap.height = stage.stageHeight - 200;

                    theMap.theStart.alpha = 0;
                    theMap.theFinish.alpha = 0;
                    addChild(Beau);
                    Beau.x = theMap.theStart.x;
                    Beau.y = theMap.theStart.y - swiper.height;

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```